# Call an route on each page

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I have a question. I added a new service PopupListener.php:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class PopupListener
{
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest()
    {
        $this->router->generate('app_popup_trigger');
    }
}
```

services.yml :

```
popup_listener:
    class: App\DesktopBundle\Listeners\PopupListener
    arguments: ["@router"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

routing.yml :

```
app_popup_trigger:
    path: /popup/trigger
    defaults: { _controller: AppDesktopBundle:Popup:triggerPopup }
```

The triggerPopupAction :

```
class PopupController extends Controller{
    public function triggerPopupAction(){
        return $this->render('AppDesktopBundle:Popup:index.html.twig', array());
    }
}
```

I want that at each route call the new route added : `app_popup_trigger`. I made somethink like that but not work. The route is not called. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Symfony 2.3 is not maintained anymore. You should upgrade to Symfony 3.x. Besides that I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. What does "I want that at each route call the new route added : `app_popup_trigger`" mean?

Comment: The idea is to call at each request this api `app_popup_trigger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html) and trigger your route with javascript. That will be easier than listeners for a popup.

Answer (score 0):

To call a specific route at the start of every request, you just need to extend your code in your PopupListener:

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class PopupListener
{
    protected $router;

    protected $httpKernel;

    public function __construct(Router $router, HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->httpKernel = $httpKernel;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $subRequest = Request::create($this->router->generate('app_popup_trigger'));
        $response = $this->httpKernel->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
        // do something with the $response here
    }
}
```

Symfony will start a new request-response cycle just for this sub-request and will return the `$response` of this cycle. Then you have to decide what you are doing with that reponse.

And then add the additional service to your service configuration:

```
popup_listener:
    class: App\DesktopBundle\Listeners\PopupListener
    arguments: ["@router", "@http_kernel"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

You can get more information about symfony sub-requests here: [The HttpKernel Component - Sub Request](https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#sub-requests). I linked the documentation for Symfony 2.3. But keep in mind Symfony 2.3 is not maintained anymore and you should consider upgrading to 3.x.

Comment: I get the error : `"No route found for "GET /app_dev.php/popup/trigger"" at /var/www/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php`

Comment: What happens if you just request `/app_dev.php/popup/trigger` in your browser?